# Select a div (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to select the div with a scrollbar were the gantt chart is displayed on this web page : http://www.jsgantt.com/ , After selecting it with firebug, I've tryied the following selector, but it doesn't work :

```js
var div=$("#GanttChartDIV #rightside");
```

Thanks for your help

Actually the problem was that the jquery library was not correctly included, thanks all.

Comment: Well, did you included JQuery?

Comment: Works for me in my console.

Comment: Since ID's (should) be unique you could just do : `$('#rightside');`

Comment: `typeof jQuery` returns `undefined` on that website, so you have to inject the library first. Or just use `document.getElementById('rightside')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like the id is "rightside" and class is "scroll2"

```
var div = $("#rightside.scroll2")
```

Comment: If selecting by id returns no elements then narrowing an empty set down  down using a class name should still return no elements...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("#rightside.scroll2")`